# How can I make a Windows 10 C++ program exploitable to buffer overflows?

Tags: c++, c, security, buffer

I'm trying to compile the following code on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buf[32];
  strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

More specifically, I am trying to learn about buffer overflows and use this sample program to learn about practical exploitation. I've configured the build options to look like this:

Compiler options:

```
/GS- /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTCu /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\buffer_overflow.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Linker options:

```
/OUT:"c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\buffer_overflow\Debug\buffer_overflow.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT:NO /PDB:"c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\buffer_overflow\Debug\buffer_overflow.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE:NO "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FASTLINK /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\buffer_overflow\Debug\buffer_overflow.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\buffer_overflow.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /TLBID:1
```

To me, this seems like it should work when I feed the program more than 32 bytes of input data from the command line. However WinDBG reports that when I run the program like this, a buffer overflow was detected and corrective actions were taken.

This is undesirable and I'd like to prevent this behavior if possible. Can anyone explain what steps I need to take to make this happen?

[Screenshot of WinDBG output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5lcR.png)

Comment: Is this in debug or release mode? And with a debugger attached?

Comment: I am building the solution using the Build menu, the only folder that exists is the "Debug" folder which contains the executable I am running from the command line outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: @MartinJames if you aren't going to be constructive or respond to the question asked, don't muddy the waters by supplying a non-useful answer.

Comment: Switch build to release.

Comment: Compile in release mode and see if the same error is raised

Comment: @PeterCrampton I didn't supply any answer.

Comment: @Slava Thank you for your reply. I changed the build to release, yet still got the same output from WinDBG.

Comment: I think you should me more familiar with the tool (VS studio) to exploit such topics. Do you still run executable from `Debug` directory?

Comment: @Slava No. I ran the executable produced in the Release folder under the project directory.

Comment: Try to replace `strcpy` with `memcpy` or copy it manually. Note: to exploit buffer overflow you need to override function stack and I do not think `main` is a good candidate.

Comment: @Slava Changing strcpy to memcpy with a fixed size greater than the size of the allocated buffer did not work either. WinDBG reports the same security exception. I don't believe the issue is with the code.

Comment: Then you need to disassemble and realize where check is performed.

Comment: Disable `Security Check` in project properties -> C/C++ -> Code generation . Disabling `Data Execution Prevention` and `Randomized Base Address` in `Linker` properties is also useful when doing this sort of analysis.

Comment: Later enable /GS, ASLR, /guard:cf, /sdl, and forced DEP so you actually learn modern vuln research on Windows. FYI you defeat all with heap spraying or ROP and info leaks where there is no heap spray. This is why everyone started sandboxing by blocking API access.

Otherwise you're basically learning stuff that hasn't been relevant since windows xp.. Linux has similar compile options, and you also need -strip there to keep symbols out and make it realistic..

no stack canaries and you basically have windows 95/98 exploits..